# Whole <DIV> wont print with beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the players from a minecraft dynmap with help of webscraper, but it only prints the name of the div. How can i get the whole html off the page?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://play.fantasycraftmc.eu:25570/?worldname=kingdom&mapname=flat&zoom=0&x=3904&y=64&z=2176#/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

div = soup.find(id="mcmap")

print(div)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
div = soup.find(id="mcmap")
```

With this:

```
div = soup.find('table', {"id": "mcmap"})
```

Comment: It will just return "none", while as seen in this photo there is a lot in it. 
https://imgur.com/a/RTmwW7e